# force html attribute to have the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to post some data to another php file using ajax. This data is on the link attribute. I am  thinking bad guy on the page could inspect the element and change the value of that particular data attribute which i want to stop this from happening using javascript.

for example: `<a href='#' data-user_id='25'> Add Friend </a>`

How do i let javascript make sure the value of data-user_id still stand the same if a bad guy inspect the page and try to change the value of the attribute ??.

below is my code but its not working the way i want:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(".save").attr("data-user_id").change(function(){
        var savefriendbtn = 57;

        if($(".save").attr("data-user_id") !== savefriendbtn){
        $(".save").attr("data-user_id","57");

            }
                })
         });
</script>
```

A code example would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Attributes of an element doesn't have a change event. If your value is hardcoded anyways then why not use that value itself while submitting rather than taking from attribute?

Comment: You cannot acknowledge access to your client-side mark-up/script as a security vulnerability and then attempt to tackle it with client-side script; it's totally futile. The real (most secure) answer, is to validate these kind of things on the server - but assume that whatever your server delivers (HTML/JS/CSS) can be modified and sent back as part of a potentially malicious request. This is why we implement sanitisation and other methods of 'cleaning up' web requests.

Comment: you should be checking from your backend if this user is not permitted to add this user as a friend, otherwise no issue if he changed the id and add another one as long as he can do that.

Comment: @gurvinder372 . The value is generated by php on a get variable  which is a user id and want to use that id number to do something on another  file without refreshing the page. So its not hardcoded. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ  . your answer is that I do real server side validation instead of worrying about a bad  guy changing the value. ....hhhhhmmm OK. but anybody has an idea on achieving what i will be happy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to prevent hacking if users change html/javascript variables on client side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186748/how-to-prevent-hacking-if-users-change-html-javascript-variables-on-client-side)

Comment: @maly - I think you're missing the point mate. Your issue is that somebody might modify something client-side that they "shouldn't" (arguable in itself), yet your proposed solution is to prevent this with something client-side. It can't happen. What's stopping them from modifying this bit of javascript? The reason I (and many others) suggest server because it's secure. Nobody should have access to it. Fundamentally the response from a server is a document download, it now belongs to the user - don't try and enforce a particular behaviour from them - you can, at best, only encourage it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly you need this function to run while the user (or bad guy) browses the page, constantly forcing the id of the element to be 57.

If I am not wrong you wouldn't need jquery.

There are two problems:

var savefriendbtn has a number type, 57, whereas you are setting it as "57", a string.

The problem should be because Document.ready only calls once, i.e. when the page loads for the first time. Hence, you would have set up an event listener or do as follows:

```
setInterval(function(){document.getElementById('save').data-user_id=57;},1000)
```

Does it help?

Then and again, the bad guy could simply change the var to another value, preventing the entire mechanism from working. I really hope this helps you.

Comment: `Then and again, the bad guy could simply change the var to another value, preventing the entire mechanism from working` so, by your own admission, this answer is useless?

Comment: @zehata. Your code is working fine but I think I have to make the variable hard to find and also do a real back-end validation. Thank you.

Comment: `I have to make the variable hard to find` - there's no point whatsoever. I give up.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ. I inspected facebook and saw facebook is having this same thing but I think the back-end script must be richer like you said. Thanks you too.

Comment: what if the user change and click before the second, something like 
`$(".save").data("user_id","99");$(".save").click();`
i think that is pretty enough to break your case

Answer (score 2):

Short answer you can't verify the change, even if its doable what prevent the user from inspecting your JavaScript and play or monkey-patch some other code and override your client-side checks,

Client-side checks was never a way to verify valid data, its a way to help but you can't guarantee or depend on it, you should have a back-end validation for this parts of code,

Validate in back-end if this user is not permitted to add this user as a friend, otherwise no issue if he changed the id and add another one as long as he can do that, and you may or may not handle error for this part as actually for me i don't care if an error explode to user if its his fault by hacking.

Comment: `Client-side checks was never a way to verify valid data, its a way to help but you can't guarantee or depend on it, you should have a back-end validation for this parts of code,` - spot on. This is the only correct answer in my opinion.